# How to check existed value in json file

Tags: json, node.js

### app.js

```js
  var permission = require('./permission.json');

for(i in permission) {
    if(permission[i] == "admin")
      console.log('admin role is present');
}
```

### json file

```js
{
    "admin": {
        "user": {
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        },
        "packages": {
            "read": true,
            "write": true
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to check the `admin` role in my json file. How to do this, any suggestion??

Comment: Use `Object.keys(data).some(k => k === 'admin');` where  `data` is the name of your json variable.

Comment: thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have an array in your json, what you are doing won't work. Instead of 'permission[i]' simply use 'i'.
Example-

```
var permission = require('./permission.json');

for(i in permission) {

    //because 'i' already contains the value of the key
    if(i == "admin") 
      console.log('admin role is present');
}
```